# Sent xml string to controller with ajax in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I need to sent **xml** string to my controller (ASP.NEt mVC 3)

method on controller is like this

 

 `[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult SetTherapyTemp(string xmlModel)
        {
            var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (PersonViewModel));
            var rdr = new StringReader(xmlModel);
           ...
        }`


 
javascript ajax call is

```
    $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST", 
                data:  xml,
                success: function (data) { alert("OK") }
    });<br></pre>
```

In methot *SetTherapyTemp* XMLModel is always null!
 How to send xmlString to controller?

Comment: how do you tie the deserializer in with your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the name of your model in the `data` parameter of your AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST", 
    data:  { xmlModel: xml },
    success: function (data) { alert("OK") }
});
```

`xmlModel` is the name of your action parameter and need to be set.